# How to initialize projection matrix with OpenGL in C

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn some OpenGL with [OpenGL SuperBible (7th edition) book](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/). To start I just want to adapt the code of the example spinnycube.cpp available [here](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/spinnycube/spinnycube.cpp), from C ++ to C.

I'm using the [vmath library](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/include/vmath.h) also available in sb7 source code.

This is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include "vmath.h"

// Remove this to draw only a single cube!
// #define MANY_CUBES

// keep track of window size for things like the viewport and the mouse cursor
int g_gl_width = 640;
int g_gl_height = 480;

// a call-back function
void glfw_window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
  g_gl_width = width;
  g_gl_height = height;
}

int main() {
  // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
  if (!glfwInit()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
    return 1;
  }

  //  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  //  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  //  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  //  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My spinning cube", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
  }
  glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, glfw_window_size_callback);
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  // start GLEW extension handler
  // glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  // get version info
  const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
  const GLubyte* glversion = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
  const GLubyte* glslversion = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION); // version as a string
  printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
  printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", glversion);
  printf("GLSL version supported %s\n", glslversion);

  // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

  // Vertex Shader
  const char* vertex_shader =
  "#version 410 core                                                  \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "in vec4 position;                                                  \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "out VS_OUT                                                         \n"
  "{                                                                  \n"
  "    vec4 color;                                                    \n"
  "} vs_out;                                                          \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "uniform mat4 mv_matrix;                                            \n"
  "uniform mat4 proj_matrix;                                          \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "void main(void)                                                    \n"
  "{                                                                  \n"
  "    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;              \n"
  "    vs_out.color = position * 2.0 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);      \n"
  "}";


  // Fragment Shader
  const char* fragment_shader =
  "#version 410 core                                                  \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "out vec4 color;                                                    \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "in VS_OUT                                                          \n"
  "{                                                                  \n"
  "    vec4 color;                                                    \n"
  "} fs_in;                                                           \n"
  "                                                                   \n"
  "void main(void)                                                    \n"
  "{                                                                  \n"
  "    color = fs_in.color;                                           \n"
    "}";

  // Shaders compilation
  GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vs);
  GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fs);

  // Create program, attach shaders to it and link it
  GLuint shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shader_programme, fs);
  glAttachShader(shader_programme, vs);
  glLinkProgram(shader_programme);

  // Vertex Array Object
  GLuint vao = 0;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray(vao);

  // Cube to be rendered
  const GLfloat vertex_positions[] = {
    -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
     0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,

     0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,

     0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
     0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,

     0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,

     0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

    -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

    -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

    -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

    -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
     0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,

     0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,

    -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
     0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

     0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
    -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f
  };

  // Vertex Buffer Object(s)

  GLuint vbo = 0;
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(float), vertex_positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  // Vertex attributes
  // 0: vertex position
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

  // 1: vertex color

  static const GLfloat green[] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
  static const GLfloat one = 1.0f;
  glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);
  glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &one);

  // Uniforms
  // - Model-View matrix
  // - Projection matrix
  GLint mv_location, proj_location;
  mv_location = glGetUniformLocation(shader_programme, "mv_matrix");
  proj_location = glGetUniformLocation(shader_programme, "proj_matrix");

  // Render loop
  while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
    float f = (float)currentTime * 0.3f;

    // wipe the drawing surface clear
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, g_gl_width, g_gl_height);
    glUseProgram(shader_programme);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
      {
          vmath::mat4 mv_matrix = vmath::translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f) *
                                  vmath::rotate((float)currentTime * 45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) *
                                  vmath::rotate((float)currentTime * 21.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) *
                                  vmath::translate(sinf(2.1f * f) * 2.0f,
                                                   cosf(1.7f * f) * 2.0f,
                                                   sinf(1.3f * f) * cosf(1.5f * f) * 2.0f);
          glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix);
          glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
      }


    // transfer proj_matrix uniform to shaders:
    float aspect = (float)g_gl_width / (float)g_gl_height;
    vmath::mat4 proj_matrix = vmath::perspective(50.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    // update other events like input handling
    glfwPollEvents();
    // put the stuff we've been drawing onto the display
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  }

  // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
  glfwTerminate();

  return 0;
}
```

As it is, I am not able to generate the spinnycube of the example. The whole screen is simply shown in black.

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

**Have I correctly initialized the projection matrix?**

Comment: Since the screen is cleared to green and you're seeing black, I doubt its a projection matrix issue, or you have at least one more problem. I would try capturing a frame in something like RenderDoc and see if anything odd standas out.

Comment: You should also check if your shader compiles and link successfully. The black screen is because you only clear with green before the first frame, but then only with black.

Comment: You are not going to be able to convert this to pure C using the vmath library as it makes use of templates.